# Export an iMovie project to QuickTime to import into another iMovie project

Tags: macos, imovie

I have iMovie '11 and wish to export an iMovie project to a mov file that I can import into another iMovie project. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Open the project, then select **Share** → **Export Movie**.

Select a destination and other options if relevant, then select Export. Once the project is exported, you can import it just like any other video.

More information: [iMovie ‘11: Export your movies to a Finder folder](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2285)